# How to hide parent div keeping child div visible in HTML, CSS?

Tags: javascript, html

While working on my HTML page, I came across a scenario where I have two div elements (lets say parent and child).

Now the case is, I want to hide parent div but display only child div of it. If I hide parent div and make child div visible, it will not work because child is inside parent div.

I can hide all child elements except those which I want to show. But is there any other solution for it?

Can I use id selector for child div and do something like nesting that id selector with parent div class?

```
  parent class:

  .KPIDashboardContainerInertiaMatrix{
      height: 175px;
      margin: 0px auto;
      color: #005686;
  }   

  child class:

  .KPIDashBoardContainerInertiaMatrixTable{
      display: table;
      border: "0";
      border-spacing: "0";
  }
```

[image: parent child div display]

Please give some suggestions on this.

Comment: If you hide parent div, all its children will also hide. You will have to use position absolute

Comment: Maybe you want to consider the semantics of your markup. Why would you want to hide parent div and show child div? Why can't they be two separate divs?

Comment: You can try something like this. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1Lbdx05/). Note you will have to move `div2` outside `div1`

Comment: I agree with @Solomon. Reconsider your markup. What you're trying to do isn't possible.

Comment: I've demonstrated how it can be done in an answer below - I do however agree that a reconsidering your markup is the likely the propper approach

Comment: @SolomonOmojola Hi...I tried that way and it was working. But the source file which I got it has the case like I mentioned. But now I changed source code to have two different  divs and it's working now :). Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Rushikesh You're welcome. Would you accept this if i made it an answer?

Comment: @SolomonOmojola sure.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply `visibility: hidden` to the parent and `visibility: visible;` to the child - I'm not sure how well this will work cross-browser as I've never actually attempted to use this in a real world project as usually if you need to do this then either something is strange with your design or something is strange with your HTML's structure.

**HTML**

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div1{
  background: #000;
  height:200px;
  width: 200px;
  visibility :hidden;
}
.div2{
  background: #f00;
  height:100px;
  width: 100px;
  visibility: visible;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xdmqz5jt/

You could potentially  also use layers ie absolute/fixed positioning, negative margins, or relative positioning to overlap 2 sibling divs which would require a restructure of your HTML.

Comment: The reason this "works" is because you're not actually hiding the parent element. You're only making it invisible. If you do it like this, and the parent element happens to be much larger in size than the child, the result on the website will be strange to say the least. Because the parent will still occupy its original space.

Comment: Nothing of the parent element is visible so I'd say it's hidden, however you are correct in that it will retain it's space which may be beneficial in some use cases (or horrible in others). This can sometimes impair hit boxes unexpectedly due to the element being invisible. I have recommended that changing them to siblings then layering, as I do think that's probably the semantically correct approach. This was the only approach I could think of that will work and satisfy the requirements of the question even if it's not the "proper" thing to do in most cases.

Comment: Ye I've seen what you recommended. I agree. Though I think the entire design is flawed in the first place if you trap yourself in an issue like this. Techically he could copy / paste the child underneath the parent and hide the parent completely with Javascript. Then just reverse it afterwards. But that's just creating workarounds instead of solving the problem at its core.